# Como verificar por input se existe string numa lista com tuplas de string e int e retornar a string com o numero em Python

Tags: python

estou tentando entender como fazer para retornar os valores de uma tupla que ta dentro de uma lista através da consulta de um usuário. a ideia é ele digitar o nome da pessoa e o programa verificar se existe essa pessoa na tupla e retornar os dados completo dela.

código:

```
lista_tupla = [("maria", 29), ("josé", 25), ("joão", 15)]
pessoa = str(input())

nome = []
idade = []
if pessoa in lista_tupla:
    for x in range(len(lista_tupla)):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            nome.append(x)
        else:
            idade.append(x)
    print(f"Nome: {nome[0]}, idade: {idade[0]}" )
else:
    print(f"Nome não está na lista.")
```

como disse anteriormente, queria que o usuário digitasse "maria" e  retornaria: `Nome: maria, idade: 29`. mas não imprime nada e eu to sem entender kkkk

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples me parece ser usar um dicionário no lugar de uma lista de tuplas:

```
dic_pessoas = {
    "maria": 29, 
    "josé": 25, 
    "joão": 15,
}
pessoa = input()

if pessoa in dic_pessoas:
    idade = dic_pessoas[pessoa]
    print(f"Nome: {pessoa}, idade: {idade}")
else:
    print(f"Nome não está na lista.")
```

Mas se realmente quiser usar lista de tuplas, o problema está na linha `if pessoa in lista_tupla`: nela, você pergunta se o *string* `pessoa` está dentro de `lista_tupla`, mas isso nunca será verdade porque o que está dentro de `lista_tupla` são *tuplas*, não strings.

Para corrigir, faça o seguinte:

```
lista_tupla = [("maria", 29), ("josé", 25), ("joão", 15)]
pessoa = input()

for tupla in lista_tupla:
    if pessoa == tupla[0]:
        idade = tupla[1]
        print(f"Nome: {pessoa}, idade: {idade}")
        break
else:  # Caso o break não tenha executado
    print(f"Nome não está na lista.")
```